# How do applications find the wifi password of local networks without brute force?

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa2-psk

I tried finding the password of my Wifi using a brute force algorithm but the WPA2-PSK encoding requires a minimum of 8 digits which means $$ 58^{8} $$ total possible wifi passwords which will take years for a normal computer to try every possible combination.

But there are available apps in the GooglePlay store which can find any wifi password in seconds. If it is not a brute force algorithm then what is used in these apps?

Comment: For you own wireless:   netsh wlan show profile name=WifiConnectionName key=clear    For some one else's you need to brute force it.

Comment: Yeah but these apps dont do it for your own wireless network, how do they achieve it?

Comment: I know, so otherwise you must brute force the password. Yes - a good password will require years of brute forcing.   ...... 
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-an-8-character-password-could-be-cracked-in-less-than-an-hour/

Comment: Wouldn’t it just be easier to reset the router? WPA2 only know vulnerability is a brute force attack.

Comment: @OP - if you wish to look:  Cain and Abel .... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain_and_Abel_(software)#:~:text=Cain%20and%20Abel%20(often%20abbreviated,brute%20force%20and%20cryptanalysis%20attacks.  ... Gone out of existence because it could not keep up with 64-bit. I used it with Rainbow Tables in XP.

Comment: I think you'll have to point to one specific app you think does this, and then we could take a look at tell you what it can or can't do. They certainly can't crack a proper WPA2 implementation with a strong password that is not known to you. They may be old tools that crack the ancient "WEP" algorithm that's been broken for two decades now, or they may exploit well known, long-fixed bugs in some manufacturers' WPA2 or WPS implementations, such as the KRACK attack from 2017.

Comment: @Spiff - Wasn't KRACK a vulnerability against WPA, which is the reason any device that didn't support WPA2 received support for it through a firmware update (when applicable) over a decade ago?

Comment: @ramhound KRACK was against WPA2 in 2017. https://www.krackattacks.com/